# Conway sequence in python

Tags: python, string

I have an assignement for which I have to write an algorithm who generates the l lines of the Conway sequence of a chosen r integer.
Example for l=8 and r=1 :

```
1
1 1
2 1
1 2 1 1
1 1 1 2 2 1
3 1 2 2 1 1
1 3 1 1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1
```

I have tried to write an algorithm in Python3, but I can't manage to get the correct output. I'd appreciate if you could help me to figure out what's wrong... Anyway, here's what I've wrote so far :

```
r = int(input())
l = int(input())

cur=str(r).strip()
print(r)
for j in range(l-1):
    r=cur
    cur=""
    i=0
    while i<len(r) :
        c=1 #counts the consecutive same "numbers"
        while ((i+c*2)<len(r)) and (r[i]==r[i+c*2]):
            c+=1  
        cur+=str(c)+" "+r[i]+" "  
        i+=c+1
    cur=cur.strip()
    print(cur)
```

And that's the output I'm getting for l=8 and r=1 :

```
1
1 1
2 1
1 2 1 1
1 1 1 2 2 1
3 1 1 1 2 2 1
1 3 3 1 1 1 2 2 1
1 1 2 3 6   2 2 1
```

I also feel that my code is pretty ugly so feel free to give your remarks

Comment: You're doing a lot of unnecessary castings/conversions between `int` and `str`. `input()` returns a string. This string is then converted to an integer and saved in `r`. The value of `r` is then converted to a string again and saved in `cur`. `r` (which is still an integer) is then overwritten by `cur` which makes `r` and`cur` the same string (so `r` is now no longer an integer).

Answer (score 0):

Really, `groupby` is built for this:

```
from itertools import groupby

def lookandsay(i):
    digits = str(i) #convert to string
    newdigits = []
    for k, g in groupby(digits):
        newdigits += [sum(1 for _ in g), k]
    return int("".join(map(str, newdigits)))

def conway(i):
    yield i
    while True:
        i = lookandsay(i)
        yield i

cw01 = conway(1)
for _ in range(8):
    print(" ".join(str(next(cw01))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this logic,
I got below code from: [HERE](https://github.com/MasterZydra/CodinGame/blob/master/Practice/Puzzles/Classic%20Puzzle%20-%20Medium/Conway%20Sequence/Python3.py)

```
r = [input()]
l = int(input())

# Write an answer using print
# To debug: print("Debug messages...", file=sys.stderr, flush=True)

for i in range(l - 1):
    temp = list()
    lastChar = r[0]
    counter = 0
    for char in r:
        if lastChar == char:
            counter += 1
        else:
            temp.extend([str(counter), lastChar])
            lastChar = char
            counter = 1

    temp.extend([str(counter), lastChar])

    r = temp
    print(r)

print(" ".join(r))
```